# Show $||Tx||_2 \leq ||(v_n)||_2 \cdot ||x||_{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $(v_n)_{n \geq 1} \in \ell ^2$ be a fixed bounded sequence of real numbers. Define a mapping $T$ on $\ell ^{\infty}$ using the formula $$T(a_1, a_2,...)=(v_1a_1,v_2a_2,...), \, \, \, \, \, x=(a_1,a_2,...) \in \ell^{\infty}$$

We can use the fact that, $Tx \in \ell^2 $ for every $x \in \ell^{\infty}$ and $T: (\ell^{\infty},||\cdot ||_{\infty}) \rightarrow (\ell^{2},||\cdot ||_{2})$ is a linear operator.

Show $||Tx||_2 \leq ||(v_n)||_2 \cdot ||x||_{\infty}$ for all $x \in \ell^{\infty}$

---

Here is what I tried:

$||Tx||_2 = \bigg( \sum v_k^2 a_k^2 \bigg)^{1/2} \leq (||x||_{\infty}^2 \sum v_k^2 )^{1/2}= (||x||_{\infty}^2 ||(v_k)||_2^2 )^{1/2} = ||(v_k)||_2 \cdot ||x||_{\infty}$

Is this OK?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Why can we bound the following like this: $\sum v_k^2 a_k^2 \leq ||x||_{\infty}^2 \sum v_k^2$???

Comment: The reason you can bound it by that is each term $a_k$ is bounded above by $\|x\|_{\infty}$ by virtue of the $\ell^{\infty}$ norm

Comment: @CameronWilliams But we bounded the sum of those a_k terms, not just each one. How do we know $||x||_{\infty}$ is larger than this sum?

Comment: I think you either made a typo or confused something. You're working with the $\ell^{\infty}$ norm which says that $\|(a_1,a_2,\ldots)\|_{\infty} = \sup_k a_k$. This by definition means that $a_k \le \|(a_1,a_2,\ldots)\|_{\infty}$ for all $k$. What this says is that, say we just take a few terms in the series, then $$v_1^2 a_1^2 + v_2^2 a_2^2 + v_3^2 a_3^2 \le v_1^2 \|x\|_{\infty}^2 + v_2^2 \|x\|_{\infty}^2 + v_3^2\|x\|_{\infty}^2.$$ Repeat ad infinitum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, it is not correct: you use the inequalities $\sqrt{x}\leq x,~x^2\leq x$, although you don't know if $x\geq 1$ (for the first), or $x\leq 1$ (for the second) - notice that they contradict each other.
Let $x\in \ell_2$,so 
 $$\|Τx\|^2_2=\sum_k(v_ka_k)^2=\sum_k v_k^2a_k^2\leq \Big(\sup_k|a_k|\Big)^2\cdot \sum_k v_k^2=\|(v_k)\|_2^2~\cdot \|x\|^2_\infty.$$

Comment: I think I fixed my one.